# Conflict in Carousel full page image slider and multi div slider in bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a carousel full page image slider in one div container and a multiple div slider in another div container in my home page.
But because of some same class names (ex : carousel slide, carousel-inner etc) they both conflicted. And multiple div slider doesn't work properly.

**Full page image slider html**

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- The slideshow -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="{{ url('images/img1.jpg') }}" alt="Los Angeles">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="{{ url('images/img3.jpg') }}" alt="New York">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="{{ url('images/img5.jpg') }}" alt="New York">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

**Multiple div slider html**

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Here is the 
[home page image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVJPk.jpg)

How to solve that ? Anybody give a suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to correctly then i am making these assumptions

1. You want a fullscreen Carousel at the top of the page and rotating images
2. You want a second carousel immediately below that so that is rotating images.
3. You are using bootstrap via the CDN links and have not pre-compiled it yourself.

Bootstrap via the CDN uses a 12 column layout with your second carousel, you have place 9 3-col's this woule be 27 columns in total. So that is probably why you are getting that rendering issue you have.

Also if you want the top carousel to be full screen you will need you use some CSS to ensure that it's set to the dimensions of the screen that it's being viewed on.

I found this example of a full screen carousel (many thanks to the developer) - [Full Screen Carousel Example](https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/full-slider/)

So so then you can use some CSS that will target your top carousel and then leave a second below. If you place it in another div container then you may have some control over that too.

The Images are applied to the backgrounds of the containers in your first carousel thus allowing you to be able to render images to the full size of the container once the height and width are set using CSS

**CODE**

```js
$('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel({
  interval: 400,
  keyboard: false,
  pause: "hover",
  ride: true,
  wrap: true
});

$('#carousel2').carousel({
  interval: 4000,
  keyboard: false,
  pause: "hover",
  ride: false,
  wrap: true
});
```

```css
header .carousel-item {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 350px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="carousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%201&fontsize=30" alt="First slide">
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%202&fontsize=30" alt="Second slide">
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%203&fontsize=30" alt="Third slide">
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%204&fontsize=30" alt="Fourth slide">
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%205&fontsize=30" alt="Fifth slide">
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%206&fontsize=30" alt="Sixth slide">
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%207&fontsize=30" alt="Seventh slide">
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%208&fontsize=30" alt="Eigth slide">
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a href="#">  
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/500x300?text=Slide%209&fontsize=30" alt="Ninth slide">
          </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I hope i understood what you are looking for also i have added in some JS for you that may help with the transition controls [BootStrap Docs Carousel Usage](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#usage) which will help with controlling each sliders activity on the screen